# Is there any other ways to send data from frontend to backend

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-post

I begin making a rating component and I'm supposed to send the rating data to the backend after the visitor selects a rating and hits the submit button, I can do it just using HTML form and submit it but my question is, is there any other ways to send this data to the backend if so what are they?

What would happen if I use JavaScript fetch to post this data to the backend or Axios?

Comment: Sorry for the title it is backend

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). You can always correct mistakes and add code using the [edit] button

Comment: `what would happen if I use JavaScript fetch to post this data to backend or axios` ? Why don't you try and get back to us if you fail?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.